# How should I update forms with uploaded files?

Tags: javascript, php

createArticle.html

```
<input type="text" name=title>
<input type="text" name=body>
...

<div id="file1" onclick="clickInput1();"> Click here to upload 1 </div>
<div id="file1" onclick="clickInput2();"> Click here to upload 2 </div>
<div id="file1" onclick="clickInput3();"> Click here to upload 3 </div>

...

<input type="file" name="files0[]" id="input1"  onchange="createPreview(...)" hidden>
<input type="file" name="files0[]" id="input2"  onchange="createPreview(...)" hidden>
<input type="file" name="files0[]" id="input3"  onchange="createPreview(...)" hidden>

...

<img id="previewFile1">
<img id="previewFile2">
<img id="previewFile3">

<button type="submit">Submit</button>
```

I'm trying to make an article page with three image uploads. However, I'm having problems when I am updating / deleting uploaded files. The uploaded files' paths are stored in DB as a stringified JSON format that would look something like this :

```
files0:['/tmp/a.png','/tmp/b.png',''] // if it has two files.
```

When updating, my controller(php) will call create a new array ($filePathArr[] with length of 3, for example) , and insert image's file path from $_FILES. If there's an empty value in $_FILES, it will look for previous file paths from the db and insert to $filePathArr[].

uploadArticle.php

$_FILES example

```
array(3) {
  ["files0"]=>
  array(5) {
    ["name"]=>
    array(3) {
      [0]=>
      string(20) "a.png"
      [1]=>
      string(20) "b.png"
      [2]=>
      string(0) "" 
    }
   ...
  }
}
```

While I can upload and update new images, I realized I cannot delete an existing image since the empty values will be replaced by existing values. While I don't want empty images to simple overwrite existing images, but I should also be able to remove images.

What would the easy way to freely edit uploaded images while preserving old images until they are overwritten/deleted specifically by the user?

I'm currently using mysql and php without any frameworks.

Comment: Not clear why you can't compare to what's already in the db

Comment: @charlietfl I can, when the controller finds an empty slot in $_FILES, it fills with previous value in db. The problem is, since empty values are being replaced with previous values, how can I delete the previous value? How should I tell the controller whether to delete the existing image or to use db's previous image when given an empty value?

Comment: `$_FILES` is a system variable containing a list of uploaded files, if any. Why are **you** putting anything in there?

Comment: @TangentiallyPerpendicular Oh, my bad, it first reads from $_FILES and creates a new array from it, containing only the file paths. Sorry I missed that.

Comment: Your problem is, that an “empty” value for those fields does not enable you to make the necessary distinction between two different scenarios. So you either need to introduce an additional parameter that helps with that (like one checkbox for each file input field, hidden from view maybe, that you check via JS, if the field is not left empty); or prevent that an empty field causes a parameter to be added to the form submission data set - by disabling the empty file input fields before submission.

Comment: In that second case, you will want to change the naming scheme to `name="files0[0]"` etc. (specifying the index upfront), otherwise you won’t be able to tell _which_ of the fields were not send. And your server-side logic that merges that with the array of existing files, will need to take this index into account, resp. that the resulting $_FILES array will have “holes” in its index.

Comment: @CBroe Thanks, will keep checkboxes in mind, but I hope there would be somewhat more elegant solution to this...